# How do I "cherry-pick" certain lines from another branch?

Tags: git

I would like to essentially do a "cherry-pick" from another branch, but instead of selecting certain commits, I just want to copy over some lines. Sort of similar to how `git add -p` works.

Comment: Ah yes, that's much easier than the long answer I gave! I couldn't find a simple solution so decided to post a question/answer for the next person. But glad there's a better option available.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to merge the branch or commit you want, then do a `git reset` followed by `git add -p`.

For example:

Get the current hash so we can reset to it later:

```bash
HASH=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Merge the branch from which you want to copy files:

```bash
git merge other-branch
```

Reset and then pick the lines you want:

```bash
git reset $HASH
git add -p
git commit -m "Copy some lines from other-branch"
```

Reset your HEAD to a clean state, so you only keep what you picked:

```bash
git add -A
git reset --hard
```

Comment: The last reset will discard any untracked files in the worktree that were present before the partial merge attempt started!

Comment: I would rather recommend using temporary branches to do the same thing rather than using reset. Assuming a partial merge of `other-branch` into `main` (assuming no modified files when starting): `git checkout -b main.tmp main; git merge other-branch; git checkout main; git diff main main.tmp | git apply -; git add -p; git commit -m "Copy some lines from other-branch"; git checkout .; git status; rm any_leftover_files_reported_by_status`.